# WSO2 API Manager : where do I have to fill my new DNS name?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've just got an internal DNS name for my WSO2 single node machine (let's say it's "apis.portal").

I've set up this name in these places so far :

```
carbon.xml:    <HostName>apis.portal</HostName>
carbon.xml:    <MgtHostName>apis.portal</MgtHostName>

api-manager.xml:        <URL>https://apis.portal:${mgt.transport.https.port}/store</URL>
api-manager.xml:        <URL>https://apis.portal:${mgt.transport.https.port}/publisher</URL>
```

It 'kind of' works, but when I go to APIs collection in store, it's like each API has kept in cache the IP of the portal instead of the name.

I've tried to delete all APIs and recreate them from scratch, but the IP is still displayed instead of the name.

There is a second incorrect url : the "requested URL" shown in swagger-ui uses IP instead of name.

This is a very annoying problem since it will create problems with most browsers except if u specifically create a security exception for certificate mismatch.

EDIT :

Incorrect URLs in store :
[image: store screen capture]

Correct URLs in publisher :
[image: publisher screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `<GatewayEndpoint>` URL too. It's under `<APIGateway>` section of api-manager.xml.

Comment: This answer is fine for the "requested URL" shown in swagger-ui, but what should I do to get this URL show the name instead of the IP (is it hardcoded in the UI page ?) : https://10.22.106.101:9443/store/apis/info?name=MyAPI&version=0.5&provider=admin

Comment: When I go to the list of APIs in publisher, the server name appears correctly for each API : https://apis.portal/publisher/info?name=MyAPI&version=0.5&provider=admin, the problem occurs only when listing APIs in store, each URL contains IP instead of name.

Comment: My answer is valid for APIs shown in store too. Are you talking about a distributed setup? Please post a screenshot.

Comment: Sure, but what should this screenshot show ? All WSO2 modules are on the same test machine, we only have an external reverse-proxy to hold the DNS name and the certificate.

Comment: I've added 2 screenshots from store and publisher, tell me if u want  to see more.

Comment: Are you saying that if you click on an API in store, it goes to a URL with  IP in it, instead of hostname?

Comment: Yes. And I don't need to click on it, I can just hover one of the APIs link like you can see circled on the bottom of screenshots, and it shows an URL with an IP in it (in publisher it's ok). Should I submit a JIRA issue ?

Comment: I just tried this and it works fine for me. Can you try again in a private browser? If you still can reproduce it, please create a JIRA with all steps.

Comment: Ok I've created a new JIRA issue. How many of these do I need to create to get a "beta tester" award ? ;)  https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5562

Comment: Didn't work in private browser either? what's JIRA url?

Comment: If you mean "private browsing", no it doesnt change anything. I've tried on different browsers on different machines anyway, clearing the cache each time. The JIRA URL is just above (I've edited the comment). Don't forget my award if it's a real bug  :)

Comment: It looks like the bug is about "tenant" management. I don't have any "tenant" set up and I expect the default "tenant" to be my DSN name and not cabon.local.ip